# Increasing and cofinal function to $\omega \times \omega_1$

Tags: set-theory

I'm having trouble to solve to following exercise, some help would be appreciated!

First define a partial order on $\omega \times \omega_1$ as follow :

$$ (n,\alpha) \leq (m,\beta) \Leftrightarrow [n \leq m \land \alpha \leq \beta] $$

The question is to prove that there is no ordinal $\lambda$ and no function $f:\lambda\rightarrow \omega \times \omega_1$ such that $f$ is increasing (for this partial order and the usual on $\lambda$) and cofinal.

I don't even know where to start...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, they are asking you to show that $\omega\times\omega_1$ has no cofinal well-ordered subset. In fact, it has no cofinal chain, but that amounts to the same thing. Let $A$ be a cofinal subset of $\omega\times\omega_1.$

Can you show that $A$ is uncountable? In other words, assuming that $A$ is a countable subset of $\omega\times\omega_1,$ can you find an element of $\omega\times\omega_1$ with no element of $A$ above it?

Can you show that $A$ has uncountable intersection with some set of the form $\{n\}\times\omega_1?$

Can you show that $A$ has uncountable intersection with **two** sets of the form $\{n\}\times\omega_1?$

Can you show that $A$ has two incomparable elements, i.e., that it can't be a chain?

Comment: Now somebody is going to come along and flag this as "not an answer" because it contains questions instead of declarative sentences.

Comment: Or because it assumes the axiom of choice... :P (Nah, I'm just kidding, of course.)

Comment: For the first one I gues you just choose an ordinal $\alpha$ in $\omega_1$ greater than any element of $A$ (which is posible because $cf(\omega_1)=\omega_1$), no element of $A$ can be above any $(n,\alpha)$.
The second one is just pigeon hole because we have an uncountable subset so it must uncountably intersect one of the countable many containers "${n}\times\omega_1$. I'm still thinking about third.
For the last one you $A$ uncountably intersect the $n$ and $m$ sets with $n<m$. But then for some  $(m,\alpha) \in A$ we find $\beta$ such that $\alpha < \beta$ : there are incomparable!

Comment: To relate to my exercise, the function is asked to be cofinal and increasing so its image is a cofinal chain in $\omega \times \omega_1$.

Comment: For the second one I think I got it, if $A$ would only uncountably intersect one of thoose sets (namely $\{n\}\times\omega_1$) then we could consider $\gamma$, the $sup$ of all the second coordinates of the $(k,\alpha) \in A$ for $k\neq n$. It would belong to $\omega_1$ as it is a "countable $sup$" and $cf(\omega_1)=\omega_1$. So $(n,\gamma)$ would not have any element above and $A$ wouldn't be cofinal.

Comment: @WrabbitW Well, in your last sentence, didn't you mean to take $(n+1,\gamma)$ instead of $(n,\gamma)?$ But I think you got the idea.

Comment: I think it works with $(n,\gamma)$ for if $n<k$ then all the $\beta$'s such that $(k,\beta) \in A$ are less than $\gamma$ beacause it is the $sup$ of such element. Or where am I wrong? Thank you for your help, I still got to study this kind of things so that the questions you asked become natural to me!

Comment: You said $n$ was chosen so that $A$ has uncountable intersection with $\{n\}\times\omega_1,$ so the ordinals $\alpha$ with $(n,\alpha)\in A$ are unbounded, so $(n,\gamma)\le(n,\alpha)$ for some $(n,\alpha)\in A.$ You defined $\gamma$ as the sup of $\alpha$ such that $(k,\alpha)\in A$ for some $k$ **not equal to** $n.$

Comment: Oh yes I see but that works with your suggestion, $(n+1,\gamma)$.